# YouTube video API not working with IDs beginning with a dash

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I am accessing data from YouTube's API, I have everything working fine but the problem I'm having is that when there's a dash (-) at the beginning of the videoID that it's not returning the json data.

```
$videoID = -FIHqoTcZog;
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q={$videoID}&alt=json"));
```

I am however able to return the thumbnail as always with it using this:

```
$thumbnail = "http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/".$videoID."/mqdefault.jpg";
```

This is the code that I use to pull the information from the above json that I want.

```
$title = $json->{'feed'}->{'entry'}[0]->{'title'}->{'$t'};
$description = $json->{'feed'}->{'entry'}[0]->{'media$group'}->{'media$description'}->{'$t'};
$thumbnail = "http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/".$videoID."/mqdefault.jpg";   
$ratings = ((round($json->{'feed'}->{'entry'}[0]->{'gd$rating'}->{'average'}, 1)/$json->{'feed'}->{'entry'}[0]->{'gd$rating'}->{'max'})*100)."%";
$views = number_format($json->{'feed'}->{'entry'}[0]->{'yt$statistics'}->{'viewCount'});
$duration = $json->{'feed'}->{'entry'}[0]->{'media$group'}->{'yt$duration'}->{'seconds'};
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're only getting a problem with IDs that have a dash in front of it? The code you pasted shouldn't be working with any Youtube ID, because the gdata feed returns, as part of the JSON, some text with the '$' character in it. That character is a PHP identifier, so you'll get 500 errors trying to run the json_decode function on whatever the feed returns.

One way to solve the problem is to use json_decode's 2nd parameter to give you an associative array rather than an object, like this:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q={$videoID}&alt=json"),true);
```

Of course, that requires you to work with an array, too, but the subsequent code changes should be minimal.

If you aren't getting errors with other videos using the exact same code, perhaps you could post it here?

Comment: Well, it does work with most other videos, there was another video ID type that didn't work but I don't remember what it was. It started with a non a-z 0-9 character though

I posted the rest of my code above, so how would I exactly change that around to work with this?